# Error al intentar ingresar objetos en las distintas posiciones de un arreglo JavaScript

Tags: javascript, nodejs, ecmascript-6

tengo una gran pregunta, espero puedan ayudarme

Tengo un arreglo al que intento ingresarles objetos en las distintas posiciones del arreglo

```
let registro = new Array();
let j = 0;
let i = 0;
let k = 0;
for (let h = 0; h < datos.length; h++) {
 if (datos[h].fecha == datos[j].fecha) {
  registro[k].push(datos[h]);
  j = h;
 }else{
  k++;
  registro[k].push(datos[h]);
  j = h;
 }
}
```

pero al ejecularlo tengo el siguiente error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
    at Object.pdfLeccionario (C:\Users\Web Master\Downloads\Luis Alava 2018-21-12\apiAtrium\models\docentes\reportesLeccionario.js:57:29)
    at rptLeccionario (C:\Users\Web Master\Downloads\Luis Alava 2018-21-12\apiAtrium\controladores\docentes\rptGenera.js:414:31)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:189:7)
```

Sin embargo al dejar al eliminar `[k]` dejandolo así --> `registro.push(datos[h]);` me ingresa pero no me divide la información ya que obviamente no especifico posición.

Que estoy haciendo mal? espero me puedan ayudar y gracias de antemano por el tiempo que me brinden.

esto son los datos que tengo

```
    { cod_leccionario: 25496,
    iso: 'C4 FOR. 1.3',
    curso: 'SEXTO AÑO DE EDUCACIÓN BÁSICA MEDIA',
    paralelo: 'A        ',
    fecha: '07/08/2018',
    hora: 8,
    materia: 'LANGUAGE ARTS',
    destrezas: 'EFL 3.2.8 Spell out key vocabulary items using the English alphabet. (Example: names, colors, animals, possessions, etc.) (spelling vocabulary from the lesson 7, and 8)',
    tareas: '',
    observaciones: '',
    profesor: 'ZAMBRANO   VERONICA',
    firma: 'No esta firmado',
    observaciones_coordinador: '',
    observaciones_inspector: '' },
  { cod_leccionario: 25498,
    iso: 'C4 FOR. 1.3',
    curso: 'SEXTO AÑO DE EDUCACIÓN BÁSICA MEDIA',
    paralelo: 'A        ',
    fecha: '07/08/2018',
    hora: 9,
    materia: 'LANGUAGE ARTS',
    destrezas: 'EFL 3.2.8 Spell out key vocabulary items using the English alphabet. (Example: names, colors, animals, possessions, etc.) (spelling vocabulary from the lesson 7, and 8)',
    tareas: '',
    observaciones: '',
    profesor: 'ZAMBRANO   VERONICA',
    firma: 'No esta firmado',
    observaciones_coordinador: '',
    observaciones_inspector: '' },
  { cod_leccionario: 25502,
    iso: 'C4 FOR. 1.3',
    curso: 'SEXTO AÑO DE EDUCACIÓN BÁSICA MEDIA',
    paralelo: 'A        ',
    fecha: '08/08/2018',
    hora: 1,
    materia: 'LANGUAGE ARTS',
    destrezas: 'EFL 3.3.9 Identify and use reading strategies to make text more comprehensible and meaningful. (Example: skimming, scanning, previewing, predicting, reading to identify causes and effects)\nEFL 3.3.8 Make and support inferences from evidence in a text with reference to features of written English. (Example: vocabulary, facts that help understand conclusions.) \n',
    tareas: '',
    observaciones: '',
    profesor: 'ZAMBRANO   VERONICA',
    firma: 'No esta firmado',
    observaciones_coordinador: '',
    observaciones_inspector: '' },
  { cod_leccionario: 25507,
    iso: 'C4 FOR. 1.3',
    curso: 'SEXTO AÑO DE EDUCACIÓN BÁSICA MEDIA',
    paralelo: 'A        ',
    fecha: '08/08/2018',
    hora: 2,
    materia: 'LANGUAGE ARTS',
    destrezas: 'EFL 3.3.9 Identify and use reading strategies to make text more comprehensible and meaningful. (Example: skimming, scanning, previewing, predicting, reading to identify causes and effects)\nEFL 3.3.8 Make and support inferences from evidence in a text with reference to features of written English. (Example: vocabulary, facts that help understand conclusions.) \n',
    tareas: '',
    observaciones: '',
    profesor: 'ZAMBRANO   VERONICA',
    firma: 'No esta firmado',
    observaciones_coordinador: '',
    observaciones_inspector: '' }
```

son 4 objetos en total, en este caso, los que tienen la fecha 07/08/2018 necesito que se guarden en una posición del objeto y los que tienen fecha 08/08/2018 en la siguiente posición y así con las demás fecha.

Comment: Fíjate bien `registro = new Array();` es un Array. Luego `registro[k]` es un ítem del Array, por lo tanto el método `push` no aplica allí. Además, ¿Dónde declaras `k`?

Comment: Podrías añadir las estructuras de datos que tienes de los objetos que estas ingresando en los arreglos? Y como menciona el amigo @MauricioContreras donde declaras k? y que valores tiene?

El detalle que tienes es que intentas hacer un push a un elemento que no es necesariamente un arreglo (o aún no lo es) en ese momento de ejecución.

Comment: @TppShaka77 la k si esta declarada, solo que al ver el error intente hacer unos cambios y olvide de volver a colocarlo, sin embargo si estaba definido antes del error me ayudas con un ejemplo?

Comment: Lo que necesitas es ordenar tus datos? deberías explicar mejor el ejercicio para que te podamos ayudar. No solo el problema, tal vez estas enfocando desde un punto de vista errado tu solución. Por otro lado el error es por que `push()` no es para insertar en posiciones especificas, sino para agregar un elemento **al final del array**. Saludos!

Comment: Aqui esta [un link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-d8dchf)! donde puedes ver un ejemplo

Comment: solo debes hacer esto `registro.push(datos[h]);`  push agrega un nuevo dato al final del arreglo, asi que no es necesario especificarle una posicion al menos que deses sobre escribirla! y por lo que veo no lo haces!

Answer (score 0):

Lo que sucede es que como esta declarando tu arreglo de registro como new Array() esta inicializandoce vacío, javascript no supone que los elementos que tendrá el arreglo sean arreglos en si mismos.

Tendrías que inicializar el elemento en la posición k de tu arreglo para ser un arreglo vacío, de modo que luego que lo recorras, puedas usar la función push del elemento.

Algo como:

```html
let registro = new Array();

for (let k = 0; k < datos.length; k++) {
  registro[k] = new Array();
  let j = 0;
  let i = 0;
  for (let h = 0; h < datos.length; h++) {
   if (datos[h].fecha == datos[j].fecha) {
    registro[k].push(datos[h]);
    j = h;
   }else{
    k++;
    registro[k].push(datos[h]);
    j = h;
   }
  }

}
```

Pero esto dependería de lo que desees lograr, la cantidad de elementos que necesitas o para que deseas organizar el arreglo.

**Lo importante del asunto es que de ese modo si te fijas, estas diciendo que los elementos dentro del arreglo 'registro' son arreglos, lo que te permitirá ingresar datos en cada una de sus posiciones**

Comment: probaste el código?  el error es por que push() no es para insertar en posiciones especificas, sino para agregar un elemento **al final del array**. Mas allá del resto de los errores que pueda tener. Saludos!

Comment: Estamos de acuerdo, si la duda que tiene es por qué le marca ese error, solo intentaba ejemplificar de que modo su arreglo registro se puede ir llenando de objetos dentro las posiciones. Sin duda, depende :) Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Comencemos con una aclaracion fundamenta. Push() solo sirve para agregar un elemento al final de un array. Por lo tanto si usas `registros[i].push(item);` y registros[i] = "lorem" estas tratando de usar push sobre un dato del tipo string, por lo tanto no va a reconocer push como un método valido. No se si me explico...

Te dejo un ejemplo de como puede hacer para ir agrupando tus datos en "registros[]" de tal manera, que registros va a quedar compuesto por 1 array para cada fecha. Algo asi:

```
registros= [
// este array va a contener todos los elementos que tenga fecha "07/08/2018"
    [
      {fecha:07/08/2018,..},
      {fecha:07/08/2018,..}
   ],
// este array va a contener todos los elementos que tenga fecha "08/08/2018"
    [{fecha:08/08/2018,..},{fecha:08/08/2018,..}] 
]
```

**Ahora te dejo el ejemplo con tus datos:**

```js
let registros=[];
let datos =[
{
cod_leccionario: 25496,
    iso: 'C4 FOR. 1.3',
    curso: 'SEXTO AÑO DE EDUCACIÓN BÁSICA MEDIA',
    paralelo: 'A        ',
    fecha: '07/08/2018',
    hora: 8,
    materia: 'LANGUAGE ARTS',
    destrezas: 'EFL 3.2.8 Spell out key vocabulary items using the English alphabet. (Example: names, colors, animals, possessions, etc.) (spelling vocabulary from the lesson 7, and 8)',
    tareas: '',
    observaciones: '',
    profesor: 'ZAMBRANO   VERONICA',
    firma: 'No esta firmado',
    observaciones_coordinador: '',
    observaciones_inspector: '' 
    },
  { 
  cod_leccionario: 25498,
    iso: 'C4 FOR. 1.3',
    curso: 'SEXTO AÑO DE EDUCACIÓN BÁSICA MEDIA',
    paralelo: 'A        ',
    fecha: '07/08/2018',
    hora: 9,
    materia: 'LANGUAGE ARTS',
    destrezas: 'EFL 3.2.8 Spell out key vocabulary items using the English alphabet. (Example: names, colors, animals, possessions, etc.) (spelling vocabulary from the lesson 7, and 8)',
    tareas: '',
    observaciones: '',
    profesor: 'ZAMBRANO   VERONICA',
    firma: 'No esta firmado',
    observaciones_coordinador: '',
    observaciones_inspector: ''
    },
  {
  cod_leccionario: 25502,
    iso: 'C4 FOR. 1.3',
    curso: 'SEXTO AÑO DE EDUCACIÓN BÁSICA MEDIA',
    paralelo: 'A        ',
    fecha: '08/08/2018',
    hora: 1,
    materia: 'LANGUAGE ARTS',
    destrezas: 'EFL 3.3.9 Identify and use reading strategies to make text more comprehensible and meaningful. (Example: skimming, scanning, previewing, predicting, reading to identify causes and effects)\nEFL 3.3.8 Make and support inferences from evidence in a text with reference to features of written English. (Example: vocabulary, facts that help understand conclusions.) \n',
    tareas: '',
    observaciones: '',
    profesor: 'ZAMBRANO   VERONICA',
    firma: 'No esta firmado',
    observaciones_coordinador: '',
    observaciones_inspector: '' 
    },
  { 
  cod_leccionario: 25507,
    iso: 'C4 FOR. 1.3',
    curso: 'SEXTO AÑO DE EDUCACIÓN BÁSICA MEDIA',
    paralelo: 'A        ',
    fecha: '08/08/2018',
    hora: 2,
    materia: 'LANGUAGE ARTS',
    destrezas: 'EFL 3.3.9 Identify and use reading strategies to make text more comprehensible and meaningful. (Example: skimming, scanning, previewing, predicting, reading to identify causes and effects)\nEFL 3.3.8 Make and support inferences from evidence in a text with reference to features of written English. (Example: vocabulary, facts that help understand conclusions.) \n',
    tareas: '',
    observaciones: '',
    profesor: 'ZAMBRANO   VERONICA',
    firma: 'No esta firmado',
    observaciones_coordinador: '',
    observaciones_inspector: '' 
    }
    ];
    
   function agruparDatos(){
   let existe =false; // boolean para saber si ya fue agregado uno con la misma fecha.
   
      //Each externo para ecorrer todo nuestro array "datos".
      datos.forEach((dato,i) =>{
          existe = false;
          //Each interno para ecorrer todo nuestro array "registros".
          registros.forEach((registro, index) =>{
            /* Verifico si dentro de registros existe 
un array donde un elemento (con verificar el primero basta) tiene la misma fecha
 que el objeto actual que se está recorriendo en datos.*/
             if(dato.fecha === registro[0].fecha){
                /* coincide, entonces ya existe un array 
que contiene los objetos con esta fecha. 
Entonces enviamos el dato.*/
                registro.push(dato);
                existe = true;
                return false;
             }
          });

          if(!existe){
          /* ya se terminó de recorrer todos los registros y no hay ningún
 grupo que contenga la fecha del dato actual, 
entonces creamos uno nuevo.*/
              registros.push([dato]);
          }
      });
   
   }
    agruparDatos();
    console.log(registros);
```

Answer (score 0):

Espero te sirva de todos modos por facebook te deje un enlace para que puedas verlo

```js
// Write Javascript code!
const original =  [
  {
    cod_leccionario: 25496,
    iso: 'C4 FOR. 1.3',
    curso: 'SEXTO AÑO DE EDUCACIÓN BÁSICA MEDIA',
    paralelo: 'A        ',
    fecha: '07/08/2018',
    hora: 8,
    materia: 'LANGUAGE ARTS',
    destrezas: 'EFL 3.2.8 Spell out key vocabulary items using the English alphabet. (Example: names, colors, animals, possessions, etc.) (spelling vocabulary from the lesson 7, and 8)',
    tareas: '',
    observaciones: '',
    profesor: 'ZAMBRANO   VERONICA',
    firma: 'No esta firmado',
    observaciones_coordinador: '',
    observaciones_inspector: ''
  },
  { 
    cod_leccionario: 25498,
    iso: 'C4 FOR. 1.3',
    curso: 'SEXTO AÑO DE EDUCACIÓN BÁSICA MEDIA',
    paralelo: 'A        ',
    fecha: '07/08/2018',
    hora: 9,
    materia: 'LANGUAGE ARTS',
    destrezas: 'EFL 3.2.8 Spell out key vocabulary items using the English alphabet. (Example: names, colors, animals, possessions, etc.) (spelling vocabulary from the lesson 7, and 8)',
    tareas: '',
    observaciones: '',
    profesor: 'ZAMBRANO   VERONICA',
    firma: 'No esta firmado',
    observaciones_coordinador: '',
    observaciones_inspector: '' 
  },
  { cod_leccionario: 25502,
    iso: 'C4 FOR. 1.3',
    curso: 'SEXTO AÑO DE EDUCACIÓN BÁSICA MEDIA',
    paralelo: 'A        ',
    fecha: '08/08/2018',
    hora: 1,
    materia: 'LANGUAGE ARTS',
    destrezas: 'EFL 3.3.9 Identify and use reading strategies to make text more comprehensible and meaningful. (Example: skimming, scanning, previewing, predicting, reading to identify causes and effects)\nEFL 3.3.8 Make and support inferences from evidence in a text with reference to features of written English. (Example: vocabulary, facts that help understand conclusions.) \n',
    tareas: '',
    observaciones: '',
    profesor: 'ZAMBRANO   VERONICA',
    firma: 'No esta firmado',
    observaciones_coordinador: '',
    observaciones_inspector: ''
  },
  { 
    cod_leccionario: 25507,
    iso: 'C4 FOR. 1.3',
    curso: 'SEXTO AÑO DE EDUCACIÓN BÁSICA MEDIA',
    paralelo: 'A        ',
    fecha: '08/08/2018',
    hora: 2,
    materia: 'LANGUAGE ARTS',
    destrezas: 'EFL 3.3.9 Identify and use reading strategies to make text more comprehensible and meaningful. (Example: skimming, scanning, previewing, predicting, reading to identify causes and effects)\nEFL 3.3.8 Make and support inferences from evidence in a text with reference to features of written English. (Example: vocabulary, facts that help understand conclusions.) \n',
    tareas: '',
    observaciones: '',
    profesor: 'ZAMBRANO   VERONICA',
    firma: 'No esta firmado',
    observaciones_coordinador: '',
    observaciones_inspector: '' 
  }
];

function groupBy(arr, prop) {
  const source = arr.reduce((prev, curr) => {
    if (!prev[curr[prop]]) {
      prev[curr[prop]] = [curr];
    } else {
      prev[curr[prop]].push(curr);
    }

    return prev;
  }, {});

  return Object.keys(source).map(key => ({ key, value: source[key] }));
}

const groupedArr = groupBy(original, 'fecha');
console.log(groupedArr);
```

Comment: lamento decirte que no me funcione lo que me dejaste :( sin embargo ya consegui lo que necesitaba